# Const always undefinied after assignment

Tags: angular, typescript, promise

I want to write a function, which creates an array of local ip-addresses based on the devices-ip.

```
  constructor(private network: UserInformationService) {
   }


  getIPArray(): Promise<any> {
    var promise = new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      const userInfo = this.network.getUserInformation();
      const _ip = userInfo.IP;
      const _subnet = userInfo.Subnet;

      let ips: string[] = [];

      const template = _ip.split('.').splice(-1, 1).join('.')


      for (var i = 100; i < 120; i++){
        let newIP = template + '.' + i;
        ips.push(newIP);
      }

      console.log('IPs', ips);
      resolve(ips);
    });
    return promise;
  }
```

I tried to set the IP and the Subnet in the constructor. But with the same result.

I can assign _ip and _subnet with the information from the UserInformationService, but 2 lanes later, _ip is undefinied.

What happend here? 
Thanks for help

Comment: Is `getUserInformation()` an async function (i.e. promise/observable)?

Comment: Why does getIPArray return a promise, instead of returning simply the array?

Comment: Aren't you missing a semicolon on `const template` ?

Comment: getUserInformation() is a sync-function and returns only a private variable.
I dont know :-D But if i tried as "normal" function, the same result...
Yea the semicolon is missing, thanks. I added it, but nothing changes.

Comment: Could it be that accessing `this` is the cause of the problem? Did you try with `getIPArray` as an arrow function?

Comment: @Andrej Semicolons are optional in JS/TS except for a few specific cases (like when the next line starts with a parenthesis). It isn't needed here.

Comment: @mbojko you mean ```this.network.getUserInformatio()```, this works, i can print the information one line below.

Comment: What happens if you change the line to `const template = userInfo.IP.split('.').splice(-1, 1).join('.')`? It shouldn't change anything, but just to double check.

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Nothing changed... I added ```console.log('userInfo', userInfo);``` one line above, this works and print the correct object.

Comment: @KreLou And the object that got printed has an `IP` property on it?

Comment: @JohnMontgomery Yes, it contains: IP: "192.168.2.100", a Subnet, and to propertys  undefnied.